# Laravel 8.6 php artisan migrate not working (windows)

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, laravel-artisan

I ran the command php artisan and it returned this.

```
PS C:\Users\15715\OneDrive\Desktop\laravel-tutorial\links> php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = links_development and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\Users\15715\OneDrive\Desktop\laravel-tutorial\links\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
    667▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a    669▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.  
    670▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 671▕             throw new QueryException(
    672▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673▕             );
    674▕         }
    675▕

  1   C:\Users\15715\OneDrive\Desktop\laravel-tutorial\links\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("could not find driver")

  2   C:\Users\15715\OneDrive\Desktop\laravel-tutorial\links\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct()
```

when I check on PDO it shows this on PDO. Not sure if this helps.

[CHECK THIS! Unable to post it to the site directly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g9nL.png)

Comment: You can use xampp and point laravel to xampp

Answer (score 0):

Did you recently upgrade your php version also because this looks more like a php extension error. e.g. `sudo apt-get install php7-mysql`

Comment: what would be the equivalent to sudo apt-get install php7-mysql, for windows. And lastly my PHP version is already PHP 7.4.8, so is that neccessary.

Comment: Ok so since you are on windows im guessing your using xamp or something. Make a page and echo <?php phpinfo(); ?>, find php.ini on that page and where its located, Now edit that file and find `;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` and `;extension=pdo_mysql.so` and uncomment them and restart the apache server

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by following these steps

1. sudo apt-get install php7-mysql
2. open php.ini file and uncomment following lines

   ;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

   ;extension=pdo_mysql.so

Then, restart the Apache server

Comment: sorry but how should i go about doing sudo apt-get install php7-mysql on windows

Answer (score 0):

Just do simple thing update your php version from 7.2 to 7.3 or 7.4 because laravel 7 required php 7.3 or greater version and also update mysql